# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

El error que obtuve al hacer Debug de mi app fue:

*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un adaptador personalizado llamado `MyAdapter` donde intento cargar un diseño que supuestamente debería insertarse en `ListView`.

### ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.NewsFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

### Layout

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageabdcf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textabcdf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### NewsFragment.java

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<String> names;
    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Fernando");
        names.add("Roberto");
        names.add("Torres");
        names.add("Urban");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Clicked: " + names.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.card_view_news, names);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }

}
```

### MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private List<String> names;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<String> names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.names.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, null);
        String currentName = names.get(position);    

        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textabcdf);
        textView.setText(currentName);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Lo que estoy esperando es algo como:

[image]

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo dentro del código que me está devolviendo este error y que seguramente se trate de un error relacionado con el contexto?

Comment: como se llama el xml de tu adapter, seguro estas llamando en otro xml en tu adapter:D. Tambien verifica que el string que le estes ingresando no sea null :D

Comment: El problema es que estas seteando un array de Strings vacíos. 
Fijate que creas el ArrayList<String> names pero cuando lo mandas al textview.setText(names) no le pasas ningún parámetro por el error está en ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola al parecer estas inflando mal la vista del item.

```
// En esta linea del getView del adapter estas inflando el layout del fragment 
v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, null);
```

Ese layout no contiene el `textView` con `id=textabcdf` por eso te termina dando `NullPointerException`

Simplemente cambia `fragment_news` por el nombre del layout del `list_item`

Comment: Hola, muy buenas noches y de antemano gracias por la respuesta. Te comento que está correcto que `TextView` con id `textabcdf` no se encuentre dentro de `fragment_news`, ya que `fragment_news` sólo es mi *fragment* en donde tengo mi `ListView`, ya que lo que estoy intentando hacer es meter mi *Layout* dentro de mi `ListView` desde el fragment. En mi  *Layout* es en donde se encuentra, efecto, el `textabcdf`, tal como lo especifiqué dentro de mi `ListView`.

Comment: @FernandoUrban entonces... cambia el R.layout.fragment_news por el R.layout.<el layout que corresponda> y te va a funcionar sin problemas. Te diria cual es el layout que corresponda, pero no pusiste el nombre del archivo, solo "Layout"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el layout que inflas `fragment_news.xml`:

```
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, null);
```

en realidad no contiene el TextView con id  `textabcdf`

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textabcdf);
```

Por  lo tanto al tratar de llamar el método setText() se esta realizando en una instacia que tiene valor null:

```
    textView.setText(currentName);
```

Asegura que el archivo  `fragment_news.xml` contenga en verdad el TextView `textabcdf`

Comment: Hola, muy buenas noches y de antemano gracias por la respuesta. Te comento que está correcto que `TextView` con id `textabcdf` no se encuentre dentro de `fragment_news`, ya que `fragment_news` sólo es mi *fragment* en donde tengo mi `ListView`, ya que lo que estoy intentando hacer es meter mi *Layout* dentro de mi `ListView` desde el fragment. En mi  *Layout* es en donde se encuentra, efecto, el `textabcdf`, tal como lo especifiqué dentro de mi `ListView`.